# Programmatically hide simple pref

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can't seem to figure out how to programmatically hide or show a setting.

I have tried this:

```
function onSwitchChange(prefName) {
  var ms = require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.option1;
  if(ms == "S"){
    require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.option2.hidden = false;
  }else{
    require("sdk/simple-prefs").prefs.option2.hidden = true;
  }
}
require("sdk/simple-prefs").on("option1", onSwitchChange);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give your pref an `oninputchanged` attribute.

see here: [MDN :: Inline Options - Setting element changed notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Inline_Options#Setting_element_changed_notifications)

it looks like you're using firefox-addon-sdk so after you make your addon to xpi. rename the xpi to zip then extract it. then edit options.xul then re-zip the files, then re-rename it to .xpi.

the edit you need to make to options.xul is find the `setting` element of `option2`. then add to it this:

```
<setting title="option1" type="string" pref="blahBlahBlah" oninputchanged="if (this.value == 'S') { document.querySelector('setting[title=\"option1\"]').style.display='none'; } else { document.querySelector('setting[title=\"option1\"]').style.display=''; } ">
    option2
</setting>
```